# fetching data in Splunk using rest api

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to import XML data to Splunk using below .py script

My concerns are:

1. Can I directly configure .py script output to  index data in splunk using inputs.conf, or do I need to save output first into a .csv file. If yes can anyone please suggest some approach so that data does not get changed after storing it into a new .csv file.
2. How can I configure that .py file to fetch data in every 5 min.

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import json
 
url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
 
response = requests.get(url)
content=xmltodict.parse(response.text)
print(content)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put your Python script into a `[script://]` stanza in inputs.conf then not only can you have Splunk launch the script automatically every 5 minutes, but anything the script writes to stdout will be indexed in Splunk.

```
[script:///path/to/the/script.py]
interval = 1/5 * * * *
index = main
sourcetype = foo
```

Comment: Thanks RichG I will try this now and confirm you back soon.

Comment: I tried above approach but somehow data was not getting index in my case, I used below config setting :

Indexes.conf

[inv]
coldPath = $SPLUNK_DB/inv/colddb
enableDataIntegrityControl = 0
enableTsidxReduction = 0
homePath = $SPLUNK_DB/inv/db
maxTotalDataSizeMB = 512000
thawedPath = $SPLUNK_DB\inv\thaweddb

inputs.conf
[script://C:\Program Files\Splunk\etc\apps\Anuj\bin\test.py]
interval = 1/5 * * * *
index = inv
sourcetype = foo

Comment: Did you restart Splunk after editing indexes.conf (it's a requirement)?  Have you checked splunkd.log and python.log?